# parts of lists in python, troubles with indexes

Tags: python, genetic-programming

I'm fairly new to python and the lists and indexing is giving me some trouble.

What I want to do is :
',
Get two individuals that represent a RPN expression, individual 1 and individual 2 for axample :

```
i1=['3', 'x', '*', '3' ,'4' ,'*', '/']
i2=['x', '4', '/', 'x' ,'4' ,'+', '-']
```

then, get a subset, of them and swap the subset , like so :

from i1 i'd take subset [ '3' ,'4' ,'*'] and from i2 ['4'] (the final 3) then do a crossover producint two outputs :

```
out1=['3', 'x', '*','4' , '/']
out2=['x', '3' ,'4' ,'*', '/', 'x' ,'6' ,'+', '-']
```

the codeI've made is the folloing, and it keeps giving me erroneous results, like off by one errors, I dont want to go into the for cycle route, as I bet there is a more pythonesque way to do so. Can any one giceme an hand please ?

```
def crossover(individual1,individual2,treedepth):
    from commonfunctions import getDepth,traverse,get_random_operator
    from commonfunctions import isOperator
    from generators import generate_RPN_expr
    #simple element mutation
    cxposindividual1 = random.randint(0, len(individual1) - 1)
    cxposindividual2 = random.randint(0, len(individual2) - 1)

    subtree1=traverse(individual1,cxposindividual1)
    subtree2 = traverse(individual2, cxposindividual2)
    individual1depth=getDepth(individual1)
    individual2depth = getDepth(individual2)
    subtree1depth=getDepth(subtree1)
    subtree2depth = getDepth(subtree2)


    output1=list()
    output1[:]=[]

    output2=list()
    output2[:]=[]


    #todo debug this !!!!

    #verificar se ecsolhemos um operador ou um nó terminal
    output1 = individual1[:len(individual1)+1-cxposindividual1-len(subtree1)]+subtree2+individual1[len(individual1)-cxposindividual1+1:]
    output2 = individual2[:len(individual2) + 1 - cxposindividual2 - len(subtree2)] + subtree1 + individual2[len(individual2) - cxposindividual2 + 1:]

    if len(output1) == 2 or len(output2) == 2:
        print('argh>>>') # problema !!!!

    #print ('CX')
    return (output1,output2)
```

The traverse function returns the subtree in the selected position. getDepth isnt being used as yet.

Thanks

Jorge

---

New Code

---

```
def crossover(individual1,individual2,treedepth):
    from commonfunctions import getDepth,traverse,get_random_operator,traverse_with_indexes
    from commonfunctions import isOperator

    r1 = random.randrange(len(individual1))
    r2 = random.randrange(len(individual2))

    st1 = traverse(individual1, r1)
    st2 = traverse(individual2, r2)

    slice1 = slice(r1, r1+len(st1))
    slice2 = slice(r2, r2+len(st2))


    i1,i2 = individual1[:],individual2[:]
    a,b=i1[slice1],i2[slice2]
    i1[slice1],i2[slice2] = i2[slice2],i1[slice1]

    return i1, i2
```

Here ,individual 1 equals  ['3.8786681846845', 'x', '+'] and st1 =  ['x'] the slice is 2,3 where I supose it should be 1,2 but ...
where individual 2 =  ['x'] st2 =  ['x'] the slice is 0,1 wich is fine !!!
I'm tempted to make some if blocks with the sizesfor exceptions, but I dont like exceptions

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem comes from the fact that **slices** in python do not include their final index. That is, [0:1] is a slice with only one element, [0], contained in it.

Your example:

```
i1=['3', 'x', '*', '3' ,'4' ,'*', '/']
i2=['x', '4', '/', 'x' ,'4' ,'+', '-']
#    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Then:

```
temp1 = i1[3:6]   # 3,4,*  
temp2 = i2[1:2]   # 4
```

Then:

```
print(i1)
print(i2)

i1[3:6] = temp2
i2[1:2] = temp1

print(i1)
print(i2)
```

Finally, because awesome, you can do this:

```
i1[3:6],i2[1:2] = i2[1:2],i1[3:6]
```

Or this:

```
A = slice(3,6)
B = slice(1,2)

i1[A],i2[B] = i2[B],i1[A]
```

**Edit**

Going farther, you can use `random.randrange()` to avoid fencepost errors, and do something like:

```
def crossover(individual1,individual2,treedepth):

    r1 = random.randrange(len(individual1))
    r2 = random.randrange(len(individual2))

    st1 = traverse(individual1, r1)
    st2 = traverse(individual2, r2)

    slice1 = slice(r1, r1+len(st1))
    slice2 = slice(r2, r2+len(st2))

    # fazer pseudonimos 
    i1,i2 = individual1,individual2
    # o fazer copias
    i1,i2 = individual1[:],individual2[:]

    i1[slice1],i2[slice2] = i2[slice2],i1[slice1]

    return i1, i2
```

---

### travese function

The purpose of this funtion is to return the 'meaningfull subtree that starts at position start, (since the program is a rpn representation)

```
def traverse(inputexpr,start):
    from copy import copy,deepcopy
    components=list()
    components[:]=[]
    components=inputexpr[0:len(inputexpr)-start+1]
    components.reverse()
    pos=0
    result=list()
    result[:]=[]
    score=0
    if isOperator(components[pos]):
        result.append(components[pos])
        score=score+getArity(components[pos])
    else:
        result.append(components[pos])
        score=score -1
    pos=pos+1
    while score>0:
        if isOperator(components[pos]):
            result.append(components[pos])
            score = score + getArity(components[pos])-1
        else:
            result.append(components[pos])
            score = score - 1
        pos = pos + 1
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

**Second Edit**

Consider this reimplementation. Does this do what you want?

```
_Arity = {op:2 for op in '*/+-%'}

def getArity(op):
    return _Arity[op] if op in _Arity else 0

def isOperator(op):
    return op in _Arity

def traverse(inputexpr, pos):
    """
    Return the meaningful subtree of inputexpr that has its upper node
    at position pos. Given an input like this:

        [ A, B, +, 5, * ]
        # 0  1  2  3  4

    Here are the expected results:

        0:  [ A ]
        1:  [ B ]
        2:  [ A B + ]
        3:  [ 5 ]
        4:  [ A B + 5 * ]

    """
    chop = pos + 1
    subtree = inputexpr[:chop]
    score = 1
    while score:
        chop -= 1
        score += getArity(subtree[chop]) - 1

    return subtree[chop:]

i1=['3', 'x', '*', '3' ,'4' ,'*', '/']
i2=['x', '4', '/', 'x' ,'4' ,'+', '-']

for i in range(len(i1)):
    print("#: {}, subtree= {}".format(i, traverse(i1, i)))
```

---

### finally works as intended

```
#output tree
output1=list()
output1[:]=[]

output2=list()
output2[:]=[]

i1p1 = individual1[:len(individual1) - len(subtree1) - cxposindividual1]
i1p2 = subtree2
i1p3 = individual1[len(i1p1) + len(subtree1):]

i2p1 = individual2[:len(individual2) - len(subtree2) - cxposindividual2]
i2p2 = subtree1
i2p3 = individual2[len(i2p1) + len(subtree2):]


output1=i1p1+i1p2+i1p3
output2=i2p1+i2p2+i2p3
```

Thanks a LOT Austin, thanks to you I found the bug that was bugging my other bugs. 
After getting it to work, I'll implement it in a more pythonesque way.
Right now I'm using this very verbose code soI dont getlots in the language details.

Again Thanks

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks for the tips, I'm still having troubles, sometimes the code works, sometimes it misses by one to the side, example, using, your last edit (wich is fantastic for its elegance), I get : ind1 = [x] st = [x] its slice is 0,1 wich is correct, but in ind2 = [x,0-0.4','*'] with st =  [x,0-0.4','*'] (full copy of it) the slice returns 1,4 wich is of by one tothe right, if I correct it with a -1 in the slices I break  the code for the other case. 
Thanks again

Comment: It appears to have something to do with the individual size being 1 or bigger ...

Comment: How can you get off-by-one if you're using the `len()` of the subtree? Also, it looks like you have an operator in there (0-0.4) - please update your question with your modified code.

Comment: (Also, it's Friday, and I'm on US/NYC time. So any further updates from me today will be soaked in alcohol. ;-O )

Comment: I dont know how the operator got there, still trying to get an hold with the comment are syntax... The code Im using is yours :)

Comment: Looking at your edit, it seems like the random range returned 2, but your traverse function produced `['x']`. What's the definition of traverse? I would have expected it to return the entire tree, since 2 is the index of the last/top node.

Comment: it returns the subtree ! from position x onwards, example : traverse ([x, x ,/, 3, +, /],4) returns  x x / ,traverse at position 0 returns the whole tree, maybe I should have given a better name to the function. im editing and pasting the traversefunction on the code. thanks – Jorge Canelhas 4 hours ago

Comment: I've added another edit with a rework of the `traverse` code. Is this what you're trying to do? (I'm a little unclear on your phrasing, but I think RPN subtrees have to go backwards, right?)

Comment: man, thats some dense python :D , I've managedtofid a off by one error in my treaverseimplementation , thanks,now I'll check the code. I HATE the way python indexed differ from c++. thanks again !!, I'll let you know !!!

Comment: Thanks Austin, I thinkI got it !

Comment: I'll apply your tips as for the list handling, but first I need to understand the lists and stuff. (Once I get enough reputation I'll upvote your help !)